# How to set QWidget background by objectName

Tags: python, pyside2

I want to use qss to set QWidget background by object name, but doesn't work.

The code in below, I can use QLable's object name to decorate background color ,

buy why I can't use QWidget's object name too ?

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Monitor(object):

    def setupUi(self, Monitor):
        Monitor.setObjectName("Monitor")
        Monitor.resize(100, 100)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Monitor)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

        self.qwidget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Monitor)
        self.qwidget2.setObjectName('qwidget2')
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.qwidget2)
        self.qlabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('rrr')
        self.qlabel.setObjectName('qlabel')
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.qlabel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Monitor = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Monitor()
    Monitor.setStyleSheet("""
        QLabel#qlabel {      <-----this can work!
            background-color: #FFBBAA;
        }
        QWidget#qwidget2 {   <-----nothing occur!
            background-color: #FFAABB;
        }
    """)
    ui.setupUi(Monitor)
    Monitor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: uh , that comment was not really in my code , just add in this post . I really can't decorate qwidget2 ... is that I use anaconda Pyside module problem?

Comment: You have tried to run it from a terminal.

Comment: I had tested it with PyQt5, I just realized that it is PySide2 and I have the same problem, it seems that it is a bug.

Comment: OK thanks , I thinks I should think another way.

Comment: Note that the problem persists even if you passed the stylesheet directly to the QWidget.

Comment: yap, I had have try that,

Comment: Report it as a bug to PySide2

Comment: I have already posted ,thank you reminder